# GCC warning with typecasts of NEON array type (e.g. int32x4x2_t to int64x2x2_t)

Tags: c, neon, gcc-warning, strict-aliasing

Consider the following MRE:

```c
#include <arm_neon.h>

void test(int64_t *r) {
  int32x4x2_t vr;

  // Do something actually interesting here instead  
  vr.val[0] = vr.val[1] = vdupq_n_s32(0);
  
  vst2q_s64(r, vr);
}
```

When compiling this code with gcc 11.2 I get the following error:

```
test.c: In function ‘test’:
test.c:9:16: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of ‘vst2q_s64’
    9 |   vst2q_s64(r, vr);
      |                ^~
      |                |
      |                int32x4x2_t
In file included from test.c:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/include/arm_neon.h:27890:39: note: expected ‘int64x2x2_t’ but argument is of type ‘int32x4x2_t’
27890 | vst2q_s64 (int64_t * __a, int64x2x2_t __val)
      |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

This is entirely expected, and can be fixed as follows:

```c
#include <arm_neon.h>

void test(int64_t *r) {
  int32x4x2_t vr;

  // Do something actually interesting here instead  
  vr.val[0] = vr.val[1] = vdupq_n_s32(0xDEADBEEF);
  
  vst2q_s64(r, *(int64x2x2_t *)&vr);
}
```

The code now compiles and actually does what I expect. However, compiling with `gcc -O3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` produces the following warning:

```
test.c: In function ‘test’:
test.c:9:17: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    9 |   vst2q_s64(r, *(int64x2x2_t *)&vr);
      |
```

Assume I don't want to change `vr`'s type `int32x4x2_t` -- I have excellent reasons for the current choice, related to the code that was omitted from the MRE. Also I can't change `vst2q_s64` to `vst2q_s32` as the resulting memory layout would change.

I'm trying to figure out the "correct" way to cast `vr` so that this code compiles without warnings. NEON intrinsics such as `vreinterpretq_s64_s32` do not work on these array types, e.g. `uint32x4x2_t`, or at least I can't find ones that do.

Something that does work (although I would appreciate a more compact solution) would be to copy each of `vr`'s elements to their corresponding elements in a variable of type `int64x2x2_t`, i.e.

```c
#include <arm_neon.h>

void test(int64_t *r) {
  int32x4x2_t vr;
  int64x2x2_t vrr;

  // Do something actually interesting here instead  
  vr.val[0] = vr.val[1] = vdupq_n_s32(0);

  vrr.val[0] = vreinterpretq_s64_s32(vr.val[0]);
  vrr.val[1] = vreinterpretq_s64_s32(vr.val[1]);
  
  vst2q_s64(r, vrr);
}
```

This works, but I keep wondering whether there's an intrinsic I've missed, or a different casting syntax that would not cause the warning above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there are no intrinsics to cast arrays of vectors, but you can write the necessary ones your self:

```
#include <arm_neon.h>

inline uint32x4x2_t vreinterpretq_u32_u16_2(uint16x8x2_t a) {
    uint32x4x2_t b={
        vreinterpretq_u32_u16(a.val[0]),
        vreinterpretq_u32_u16(a.val[1]),
    };
    return b;
}
```

The other legitimate method requires memcpy:

```
uint32x4x2_t vreinterpretq_u32_u16_2(uint16x8x2_t a) {
    uint32x4x2_t b;
    memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof(a));
    return b; 
}
```

Both of these compile to the same assembly: `ret`

I would only speculate that the lack of these intrinsics is due to C not supporting overloading, which will cause an explosion in the number of added function prototypes.

One can also simply write

```
uint32x4x2_t tmp;
memcpy(&tmp, &original, sizeof(original));
```

Or maybe this actually calls for a macro:

```
#define VCAST2(a, func) { func(a.val[0]), func(a.val[1]) }
#define VCAST3(a, func) { func(a.val[0]), func(a.val[1]), func(a.val[2]) }
#define VCAST4(a, func) { func(a.val[0]), func(a.val[1]), func(a.val[2]), func(a.val[3]) }

uint32x4x2_t tmp2 = VCAST2(a, vreinterpretq_u32_u16);
uint32x4x3_t tmp3 = VCAST3(b, vreinterpretq_u32_s64);
uint32x2x4_t tmp4 = VCAST4(c, vreinterpret_u32_f32);
```

Comment: Besides, the macro approach would also work outside casts: `uint32x4x3_t sum = VOP2_3(a,b,vaddq_u32);  uint8x16x2_t tmp2 = VOP1_2(a, vcntq_u8); float32x2x3_t tmp3 = VOP3_3(a,b,c, vmla_f32);`